# Check size in bytes of variable using Julia

Tags: julia

**Question:** How do I check the size *in bytes* of a variable using Julia?

**What I've tried:** In Matlab, the `whos()` function provided this information, but in Julia that just provides the variable names and module. Browsing the standard library in the Julia manual, `sizeof()` looked promising, but it only appears to provide the size of the *canonical* binary representation, rather than the current variable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### sizeof works on variables too

#### [sizeof(a::Array{T,N})](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/array.jl#L23)

returns the size of the array times the element size.

```
julia> x = [1 2 3 4]
1x4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4

julia> sizeof(x)
32

julia> x = Int8[1 2 3 4]
1x4 Array{Int8,2}:
 1  2  3  4

julia> sizeof(x)
4
```

#### [sizeof(B::BitArray{N})](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/bitarray.jl#L1874)

returns chunks; each chunk is 8 bytes so can represent up to 64 bits

```
julia> x = BitArray(36);
julia> sizeof(x)
8 

julia> x = BitArray(65);
julia> sizeof(x)
16
```

#### [sizeof(s::ASCIIString)](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/ascii.jl#L15) and [sizeof(s::UTF8String)](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/utf8.jl#L101)

return the number of characters in the string (1 byte/char).

```
julia> sizeof("hello world")
11
```

#### [sizeof(s::UTF16String)](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/utf16.jl#L77) and [sizeof(s::UTF32String)](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/utf32.jl#L68)

Same as above but with 2 and 4 bytes/character respectively.

```
julia> x = utf32("abcd");
julia> sizeof(x)
16
```

#### Accordingly other [strings](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/string.jl)

```
sizeof(s::SubString{ASCIIString}) at string.jl:590
sizeof(s::SubString{UTF8String}) at string.jl:591
sizeof(s::RepString) at string.jl:690
sizeof(s::RevString{T<:AbstractString}) at string.jl:737
sizeof(s::RopeString) at string.jl:802
sizeof(s::AbstractString) at string.jl:71
```

#### [core values](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/operators.jl#L171)

returns the number of bytes each variable uses

```
julia> x = Int64(0);
julia> sizeof(x)
8

julia> x = Int8(0);
julia> sizeof(x)
1

julia> x = Float16(0);
julia> sizeof(x)
2

julia> x = sizeof(Float64)
8
```

one would expect, but note that Julia characters are wide characters

```
julia> sizeof('a')
4
```

### getBytes

For cases where the layout is more complex and/or not contiguous. Here's a function that will iterate over the fields of a variable (if any) and return of sum of all of the sizeof results which should be the total number of bytes allocated.

```
getBytes(x::DataType) = sizeof(x);

function getBytes(x)
   total = 0;
   fieldNames = fieldnames(typeof(x));
   if fieldNames == []
      return sizeof(x);
   else
     for fieldName in fieldNames
        total += getBytes(getfield(x,fieldName));
     end
     return total;
   end
end
```

#### using it

create an instance of a random-ish type...

```
julia> type X a::Vector{Int64}; b::Date end

julia> x = X([i for i = 1:50],now())
X([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  …  41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50],2015-02-09)

julia> getBytes(x)
408
```

Comment: Very comprehensive, thank you. I notice however, that `sizeof` doesn't work for my own composite types, e.g. a type that has one field of type `Vector{Float64}` will always return `8` for `sizeof`, regardless of the length of the vector stored in that field. Does this mean I should extend `sizeof` for each of my composite types? Is the best way to do this simply to add up the `sizeof` each field? Thanks again for responding.

Comment: I've added a function that might help you.

Comment: Brilliant, a thoroughly complete answer!

Comment: Both of given methods does not work for StatsBase.Weights variables, which are DataType. The solution is using Base.summarysize given in the other answer.

Answer (score 15):

## The function [Base.summarysize](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.summarysize) provides exactly that

It also includes the overhead from the struct as seen in the examples.

```
julia> struct Foo a; b end

julia> Base.summarysize(ones(10000))
80040

julia> Base.summarysize(Foo(ones(10000), 1))
80064

julia> Base.summarysize(Foo(ones(10000), Foo(ones(10, 10), 1)))
80920
```

However, care should be taken as the function is non-exported and might not be future proof

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this solution! Although it is probably worth adding that this function is non-exported, with the usual caveats about future-proofing that entails.

Answer (score 6):

In julia 1.6, `varinfo()` shows sizes:

```
julia> a = 1;
julia> v = ones(10000);
julia> varinfo()
  name                    size summary                      
  –––––––––––––––– ––––––––––– –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
  Base                         Module                       
  Core                         Module                       
  InteractiveUtils 250.022 KiB Module                       
  Main                         Module                       
  ans               78.164 KiB 10000-element Vector{Float64}
  v                 78.164 KiB 10000-element Vector{Float64}
  a                    8 bytes Int64
```

For specific variables, either use pattern matching (`r"..."` is a  [regular expression](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#Regular-Expressions)):

```
julia> varinfo(r"^v$")
  name       size summary                      
  –––– –––––––––– –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
  v    78.164 KiB 10000-element Vector{Float64}
```

or combine the  [`Base.summarysize`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.summarysize) from [Korbinian answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54738759/3565696) with [`Base.format_bytes`](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-print-human-readable-byte-counts/31877/3):

```
julia> pretty_summarysize(x) = Base.format_bytes(Base.summarysize(x))
pretty_summarysize (generic function with 1 method)

julia> pretty_summarysize(v)
"78.164 KiB"
```

*Edit: beware that `summarysize` had a [bug](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/40773), at least in 1.5.3 and 1.6.1. `varinfo` was affected as well. It is fixed (tested with `1.7.3`).*